# Please help to understand relation between simplified and real optical system for triangulation process

Tags: optics

I'm far away from being an optical engineer, so I require some assistance.
I have an optical system consisting of industrial camera and lens (manual iris + manual focus).

1)Lens documentation states it is 6mm focus lens, then what is actually happening when "focus" ring is rotated to get sharper image on several WD? Does it affect focus distance?

This setup (with addition of laser line) is used to obtain depth information by triangulation. Math behind triangulation needs two parameters - Gamma angle and distance between laser and camera axes (by) (shown on image).[image: Triangulation system geometry]

My question is about "by". For simplified system "by" - distance between focus point (red one) and laser plane. The point location in real world is important for future conversion of depth information into 3d point cloud. Simplified system means it uses pinhole camera model.  But the real system has lens, with Front Principal Plane (FPP) - place where picture is actually "created". Then lens combination "move/undistort" created image to focus point, right?

[image: Lens cross section]

2. Then, what is location of focus point (red one on triangulation system picture) in the real camera + lens system?

Comment: The definition of all the relevant lens terms is found , e.g., at https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/application-notes/optics/understanding-optical-lens-geometries/

Comment: For your purposes, aberrations don't matter and even focus doesn't appear to be critical - you just want the centroid of the image spot to be able to calculate angles.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, thank you for the reply. Yes, for triangulation calculation precise position of this point doesn't matter. But, knowledge of this point position in world coordinates lets me transform obtained pointcloud  to put it in proper place.